# iPhone Simulator not getting launch

Tags: xcode4, xcodebuild

My requirement is to run the target file which makes the simulator launch and run the script from the terminal.

I am able to execute the build file successfully from the terminal using (xcodebuild -project MyPro. xcodeproj -target "MyPro copy" -configuration "Debug" -sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk) but the simulator is not getting launched.

Answer (score 1):

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator

for xcode 4

Answer (score -2):

you can launch it from within xcode without any problem,simply select iphone/ipad simulator in the upper left corner and click play